# IE, Iframes, and multiple classes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I'm having an issue with multiple classes assigned to one element and IE (9 and less).

When you look at the page itself, all styles for all classes get applied to the element. For instance:

```
<a href="blah" class="c1 c2">blah</a>
```

The styles for c1 and c2 are both applied to the hyperlink.

The problem occurs when I view the page within an iFrame. It's as if only the first class is seen and the second class is ignored. It works fine on Firefox.

Comment: Jason, if you take a few minutes to create a demo of the issue, it would help you and potential answers a great deal. You may even find the source of the issue in the meantime.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the frame? And not, perhaps, that you have a Quirks mode triggering Doctype when you use the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All style sheets must be included both into your main page and into iframe page.
Because there's an independent document in the iframe, it does not "see" the style sheet of the main page.